# auto.arima() not differencing while it should?

Tags: r, time-series

I am using `auto.arima` from `forecast` package to create an ARIMAX model.
The dependent variable and the regressors are non-stationary. However, `auto.arima()` returns a model `ARIMA(0,0,0)`.

Should I worry about this? Should I force `auto.arima()` to difference my time series, specifying `d=1` ?

If I don't put any regressors in my model, it does detect non-stationarity, ending up with `ARIMA(0,1,1)`.

*I know the problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349400/auto-arima-is-not-showing-any-order/38503980?noredirect=1#comment64408081_38503980) topic, but my dataset is bigger (about 90 observations), thus the answer given is not satisfying.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto.arima` did nothing wrong. Note you have an additive model:

```
response = regression + time_series
```

When you include regressors / covariates, non-stationarity is captured by regressors / covariates, so time series component is simple. For your data, you end up with `ARIMA(0,0,0)`, which is white noise.

When you don't have regressors / covariates, non-stationarity has to be modelled by time series, thus differencing is needed. For your data, you end up with `ARIMA(0,1,1)`.

Of course, those two models are not the same, or even equivalent. If you really want some model selection, use the AIC values by both models. But remember, **all models are wrong; some are useful**. As long as a model can not be rejected at certain statistical significance, it is useful for prediction purpose.

Comment: if you post your data or email it to me .. I might be able to help you further.